# Facebook like button shows wrong like count (very low some periods)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm using the new Facebook like/share button on a website.

I'm using the HTML5 version, the URL is always the same (only http no https and only used in the frontpage). So not different URLs at all.

Everything works fine with liking/sharing but the like count is really really weird. The like count seems to fluctuate like crazy. Yesterday the page had 76 likes but this morning it's down to only 6. The site has done this the last couple of days. Show the correct like count for a couple of hours and then a very low number (4 or 6 I think) only to go back to the correct amount a couple of hours later.

First I thought is was some kind of caching problem on facebooks side but this has happened the last few days now and I can't figure out why.

https://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com always shows the correct amount even when the HTML output on the site doesn't. Very weird.

Any idea what could cause this or if there is anything I can do abut it?

Comment: i have the same problem, my like count dropped from 1.2k to 21 in one day :) this is big problem for a business